# How to install kohana on subdomain?

Tags: frameworks, installation, subdomain, kohana

[enter link description here](http://www.appliedmath.url.ph)-is the  place where I installed Kohana, but it gives an error.

**Kohana_HTTP_Exception [ 404 ]: The requested URL / was not found on this server.**

In the bootstrap written only one route (by default):

```
Route :: set ('default', '(<controller> (/ <action> (/ <id>)))')-> defaults (array (      'controller' => 'page','action' => 'index',));));
```

and in the  htacces written (by default too)

I installed application on local machine - it works perfect, no errors

please help me

Comment: Have you set the `base_url` properly in bootstrap.php?

Answer (score 0):

The default action for the 'default' route is 'test' in your case.

How do I know?
I clicked on one of the 'arguments' links on the error page. This is a part of it:

```
protected _route => object Route(5) {
    protected _filters => array(0) 
    protected _uri => string(32) "(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))"
    protected _regex => array(0) 
    protected _defaults => array(2) (
        "controller" => string(7) "welcome"
        "action" => string(4) "test"
    )
    protected _route_regex => string(95) "#^(?:(?P<controller>[^/.,;?\n]++)(?:/(?P<action>[^/.,;?\n]++)(?:/(?P<id>[^/.,;?\n]++))?)?)?$#uD"
}
```

The URL http://www.appliedmath.url.ph/welcome/index works just fine.

Kohana's default error page can be really usefull during development. Go play with it a bit: click every underlined text.